# Extraer de un string todas las urls que se hallen en él utilizando .Net

Tags: c#, regex

Estoy probando varias expresiones regulares, pero no consigo que me cubra todos los casos que necesito.
La idea es que cuando alguien introduzca un texto en un textarea y el texto contenga varias url´s, al guardalas, se puedan detectar.
La que más se acerca a lo que busco es esta, me encuentra las que empiezan por:
http://......
https://.....

No consigo encontrar la que me cubra estos casos:

```
www.google.es
google.es
google.com
```

Os dejo el regex que estoy usando:

```
((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)
```

Comment: Eso es complicadisimo, lo mismo sucede al validar direcciones de correo, no hay metodo para eso, siempre se te va a quedar algo

Comment: Puedes intentar con esto: (?<base>(?<protocol>ftp|http(s?)):\/\/)?(?<url>\w+(.\w+)+)

Comment: Puedes añadir más ejemplos de entradas que deban ser verificadas?

Comment: Prueba esta expresión, te captura toda forma de url válido o al menos es lo pienso: `/(?:(?:([a-zA-Z]+:\/\/)?(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@%_\+~#=]+\.)+(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@%_\+~#=]+)))(?::(\d+))?(?:(?:\/[-a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+,\\\/:;=@\[\]._~%]*)*)(?:(?:(?:\#|\?)[-a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+,\\\/:;=@\[\]._~]*)*))/gi`, si es lo que quieres te la explico  en la respuesta. Al menos tus ejemplos los captura. Prueba con algo más difícil. Y si quieres lo pruebas con correos electrónicos